# How to look up the last occurance of one of 4 recurring symbols from a row that includes various other data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Per the attached image, I am attempting to create a formula that would accomplish the following:

1. Look up the most recent of four recurring characters in a row of other text. Screen shot of the four symbols is included in the attached image as well (Circled Digits 1,2,3, and 4  - other characters in row are all text)
2. Identify what date-value it is associated with the last symbol in the column header (row 12): Example: the last yellow 2 in cell J13 is associated with 06 Jan 2019
3. Calculate and display in cell A13 how many weeks it has been from that date to the current date (A11).

---

My biggest frustration so far has been how to find the last of a group of repeating symbols (or value). For example, the last Yellow 2 should be J13 but I have only been able to get C13.

[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1391624/edit) to make it clearer? Sample data, expected outcome, what you've tried so far and how it fails to meet expectations would all be useful

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is that will need to find the max column in your range for each different symbol as per cells

Using helper cells for each, find the address for your header cell from the max of the range of columns B3 to K3 like this in my example cell K6 add the formula in L6

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MAX(IF($B$3:$K$3=$K6,COLUMN($B$3:$K$3)-COLUMN(INDEX($B$3:$K$3,1,1))+2))))
```

This need to be added as an array i.e. Ctrl+Shift+Enter

repeat for your other cells you wish to match drag down from L6 to L9

then use `=MAX(L6:L9)` to give you the latest cell date

[image: Max column Example]

**#### EDIT ####**

Taking this solution further with a small tweek, you can then match multiple criteria without helper cells by using or (+) in the if statement.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MAX(IF(($B$3:$K$3="❶")+($B$3:$K$3="❷")+($B$3:$K$3="❸")+($B$3:$K$3="❹"),COLUMN($B$3:$K$3)))))
```

The INDIRECT function returns the date reference from Row 2 as the result of ADDRESS Column returned by the ORed Max If function.

Just remember this still needs to be added as an array i.e. Ctrl+Shift+Enter

**#### EDIT 2 ####**

Response to Calculate and display in cell A13 how many weeks it has been from that date to the current date (A11). In cell A13 as an array Use DATEIF with Range From To and days "d" as criteria then divide by 7

```
=DATEDIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MAX(IF(($B$3:$K$3="❶")+($B$3:$K$3="❷")+($B$3:$K$3="❸")+($B$3:$K$3="❹"),COLUMN($B$3:$K$3))))),TODAY(),"d")/7
```

format cell as number or general

Comment: THANK YOU! This was helpful but I was trying to avoid having to use the helper cells for each. After playing around with what you provided here combined with other research online, I eventually got it to work using this:  =MAX(INDEX($C$3:$S$3,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(COLUMN($C4:$S4)*("❶"=$C4:$S4))-2)),INDEX($C$3:$S$3,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(COLUMN($C4:$S4)*("❷"=$C4:$S4))-2)),INDEX($C$3:$S$3,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(COLUMN($C4:$S4)*("❸"=$C4:$S4))-2)),INDEX($C$3:$S$3,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(COLUMN($C4:$S4)*("❹"=$C4:$S4))-2)))